# Is it okay to import interfaces with the `import type {x} from 'y'` syntax in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypesScript 4.4, using the `import type` syntax for interfaces works fine and there are no errors when compiling.

```
export interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

```
import type { Person } from './interfaces';

const developer: Person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
};
```

I'm looking to know if it's fine to continue to import interfaces this way, because I know that it isn't the common way to import an interface.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the question is here. Are you asking if type-only imports don't have side effects?

Comment: @LeoDog896 I'm saying it looks strange that `import type` syntax works for importing an interface. So I'm looking to know what issue may arise from using it even though I know that it isn't the common way to import an interface.

Comment: I do recommend rephrasing it around that -- the whole *safe* thing kind of throws it off. I'll see if I can answer this.

Comment: @LeoDog896 Good call out. I updated the title and the body to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely referring to type aliases - both type aliases and interfaces fall under the general umbrella of types. A lot of the common types are covered in the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html). These types include things such as Type Aliases, Interfaces, and also Enums.

Do note that when importing *any* types (including interfaces), no side-effects (that may be caused by a non-type import) will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in a wrong place

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types

> Prior to TypeScript 3.8, you can import a type using import. With TypeScript 3.8, you can import a type using the import statement, or using import type.
>
> ```
> // Re-using the same import
> import { APIResponseType } from "./api";
> // Explicitly use import type
> import type { APIResponseType } from "./api";
> // Explicitly pull out a value (getResponse) and a type (APIResponseType) 
> import { getResponse, type APIResponseType} from "./api";
> ```
>
> Any explicitly marked type import is guaranteed to be removed from your  JavaScript, and tools like Babel can make better assumptions about your code via the isolatedModules compiler flag. You can read more in the 3.8 release notes.